# Issue with scanf("%s")

Tags: c++, scanf

```
include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int l,k;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d %d",&l,&k);
        char ch[l+1];

        /****/     scanf("%s",ch);

        printf("Are we here");
        char ci=ch[0];

        int flips=0;
        int count=0;
        for(int j=0;j<l;j++)
        {
            if(ch[j]==ci)
        {   
                count++;
                if(count>k)
                {
                flips++;
                count=1;
                if(ci=='1')
                {
                    ci='0';
                    ch[j]='0';
                }
                else if(ci=='0')
                {               
                    ci='1';
                    ch[j]='1';
                }
                }
            }
        else if(ch[j]!=ci)
        {

            if(ci=='1')
            ci='0';
            else if(ci=='0')
            ci='1';
            count=1;        
        }   


        }

        printf("\n%d",flips);   
        printf("\n%s",ch);    

    }

    return 0;
}
```

An input with 3 test cases and each test case having two lines of input.

```
3
2 1
11
2 2
11
4 1
1001
```

should give the output

```
1
10
0
11
2
1010
```

This is basically a code that does some standard programming contest stuff. It takes in the number of test cases, and for each of the test cases prints out the required answer in two lines .Now when I type all the inputs line by line it works fine and I get all the outputs. But when I just copy paste all the inputs together I only get everything but the last output and I have to press the enter key to get the last output. Now I did some basic debugging and found out that it has something to do with the `scanf("%s",ch)` line of code. Any help.. Also I felt the logic of the program doesnt matter. I'm missing something far more basic here...

Comment: Remove the empty lines and re-indent your code.

Comment: Warning: this code is exploitable. You shouldn't EVER use `scanf("%s")`

Comment: What do you suggest??

Comment: you can use std::cin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "\r\n" are not copied when you copy paste the text

Comment: But why only for the last input

Comment: well maybe cause there is none. you can paste your text to text editor like notepad++ and turn on invisible character. you will see if there is a newline.